# No DomainDataSource in toolbox in Visual Studio

Tags: ria, toolbox

In Brad Adams' blogged walkthrough of the new RIA goodies, he mentions that you can simply drag a DomainDataSource from the toolbox to your XAML.

All of my RIA kit came from links from that blog and I definitely have the July CTP, yet in my toolbox there is conspicuous absence of DomainDataSource.

What arcane rituals must I undertake to be worthy of toolboxification and the accompanying privileges of automated addition of references to project and XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A helpful Microsoftie responded on another forum. If you right-click the Silverlight controls section of the toolbox for the context menu and add a control you can browse to Silverlight controls and tick DDS in the list. Too easy.